# Finding Recursive Function

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)=e^\frac{-1}{x}$
>   
> Prove in induction that the general form of the n-th derive is:
>   $$f^{(n)}(x)=P_n(\frac{1}{x})\cdot e^\frac{-1}{x}$$

For $n=0$: $P_0(x)=1$

Assume for n: $f^{(n)}(x)=p_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$

And prove for $n+1$: $f^{(n+1)}=p_{n+1}(x)=(P_n(x))^n-P_n'(x)^{n+1}$

It does not seems right, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f^{(n)} (t) =p_m (t^{-1}) e^{-t^{-1}}$ where $p_m $ is a polynomial with real coefficients of degree $m.$
Then $$f^{(n+1)} (t) =\left(p_m (t^{-1}) e^{-t^{-1}}\right)'=p'_m (t^{-1} ) \cdot (-1)t^{-2} \cdot e^{-t^{-1}} + p_m (t^{-1})(-1)t^{-2} \cdot e^{-t^{-1}}=(p'_m (t^{-1} ) \cdot (-1)t^{-2}  + p_m (t^{-1})(-1)t^{-2}) \cdot e^{-t^{-1}} =p_{m+2} (t^{-1})e^{-t^{-1}}.$$